# You can always trust this man to do it

Tags: riddle

> We start just the same, but in the end we are not even similiar
>
> As comes Night, and the death of the light, so from one should you go to the other
>
> One is not nice, and the other is needed, but both can be done, and even succeeded
>
> You can always trust a dishonest person to do them both everyday.

What are we?

Hint:

> You can always trust this man to be dishonest and do one of them everyday

Hint:

> What does Night bring?

Hint:

> Night does something very specific to something else

Comment: All I got so far is that it is likely to be two words which are opposites but start with same letter

Comment: You're on the right track on the words part starting the same. However opposite is such a strong word. Not even similar should be the hint there.

Comment: Not certain what you mean there?

Comment: Words can be similar in many ways. Meanings, sounds, length, spelling.

Comment: Necessary. Also think about what night brings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are...

> Lie and lie

We start just the same, but in the end we are not even similiar

> both start with L but have different meanings, also simi(liar) misspelled hint

As comes Night, and the death of the light, so from one should you go to the other

> Lie during the day (tell lies) and lie down during the night (rest, sleep)

One is not nice, and the other is needed, but both can be done, and even succeeded

> Being dishonest or telling lies is not good, but lying down (rest) is needed, but both can be done.

You can always trust a dishonest person to do them both everyday.

> A dishonest person will do both everyday: tell lies and lie down.

Comment: Bingo. The second hint was probably the hardest. Night brings death to the day, so day, die but a lier lays.

Comment: Credit to @ohmygawd

Comment: Can you add explanation?

Comment: Sure, just did.

Comment: Also your explanation to the both successfully: If you lie successfully, you have to lay low successfully

Comment: @RobertMennell Because "Night" was capitalized, I was going around looking for clues related to someone named "Night." M. Night Shyamalan, the ultimate liar, plot twist extraordinaire!

Comment: @SendersReagent that... somehow fits? but still wrong. It was to emphasis the relationship of Night and Day. Although I'm sure most people put it as night and day, I'm referring to them properly here.

Comment: One doesn't really lay, though. You can lay something down, but you lie down to go to sleep. I.e. laying is something you do to something else.

Comment: @Waldo It was actually more of a criticism of the original question. I think the puzzle-writer may have made the same mistake.

Comment: Lay is also the past tense of lie(down)

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure one of the words is

> "lie", given the liar/lie down (to sleep) meanings which fit neatly with both the night theme, the dishonest theme and the 'does it every day' theme

The other one, tho? I'm at a loss.

Comment: SO CLOSE! So damned close!

Answer (score 0):

Is it?

> Fraud and Fight

We start just the same, but in the end we are not even similar

> start by same letter "F"

As comes Night, and the death of the light, so from one should you go to the other

> Fraud in Day, and Fight by the Night

One is not nice, and the other is needed, but both can be done, and even succeeded

> Fraud is not Nice, and fight is needed for a gangster to survive. Both can be executed and completed successfully.

You can always trust a dishonest person to do them both everyday.

> dishonest person use them everyday.

Comment: Nope. Not the first right letter. Close in the idea though.

Comment: too many combination of words are possible, a positive hint might help.

Comment: You're completely ignoring what Night brings(I referred to it as a noun for a reason)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Sleep and snore

1.

> They start with s but mean completely different

2.

> not sure

3.

> Snoring is not nice but sleep is needed and both can be down at once you can snore while sleeping

4.

> dishonest will always sleep

Comment: What does Night bring?

Comment: Is it Darkness?